# Backstage.io: is there a way to document events consumed and produced by a component?

Tags: backstage

I am planning to adopt backstage.io in our organization. Parts of our architecture is based on asynchronous microservices that produce / consume events in Kafka topics.

I could not figure out an obvious way to model this. Async APIs are the closest one, but this is not exactly the same, as we use Avro schema.